# appendChild to multiple pages

Tags: javascript, typescript, appendchild

Is it possible to use appendChild to multiple pages? I have working a function that appends text to my first page. But it also needs to be appended to another page. Here's what i have tried:

```
function displayChatBericht() {
// get, & create elements
const chatVeldModerator: string = (document.getElementById('chat_veld') as HTMLTextAreaElement).value
const berichtenVeldModerator: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("berichten_veld")
const creeerElementModerator: HTMLParagraphElement = document.createElement('p');
const textNodeModerator = document.createTextNode(chatVeldModerator)

// append element to DOM
berichtenVeldModerator?.appendChild(creeerElementModerator)
creeerElementModerator.appendChild(textNodeModerator)
localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, chatVeldModerator)

// set local storage
let localStorageKey = "chatBerichtModerator" + Date.now()

^ code up here is working
// get id of the other DOM page
const berichtenVeld: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("berichten_veld_gebruiker")

// append to the other DOM page
berichtenVeld?.appendChild(creeerElementModerator)
creeerElementModerator.appendChild(textNodeModerator)
}
```

Why are the last three rules of my code not working?

Comment: what do you mean by "another page"?

Comment: An other HTML page the appended item needs to be in two pages

Comment: Because when changing pages, your browser will reload the content again (hard refresh), you need to add your JS code in all pages that you need to insert elements in. you can get pathname by `window.location.pathname` and insert certain items based on your specific URL.

Comment: @AmirMeimari JS files are included in both pages, what do you mean with  insert certain items based on specific URL with```window.location.pathname```?

Comment: For example you want to inset Element `A` into home page that has a pathname `/home` and you want to insert Element `B` into about page that has a pathname `/about`. you have to check `if (window.location.pathname) === '/home'` then insert element `A` if not and it was something like `if (window.location.pathname) === '/about'` then insert element `B`